# Disable cols with TextAreaFor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

OK I am using MVC 4 with Bootstrap and running into a problem with TextAreaFor and columns.  By default if you don't set the col/row the system sticks 2/10 as the default.  Obviously if you enter the row/col it will use that.  The problem is with forms using Bootstraper it is better if you just leave it blank.  Anyone come up with a good way of disabling col for TextAreaFor.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m=> m.Comments, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

outputs:

```
<textarea cols="20" htmlAttributes="{ class = form-control }" id="Comments" name="Comments" rows="2"></textarea>
```

but I want this:

```
<textarea htmlAttributes="{ class = form-control }" id="Comments" name="Comments" rows="2"></textarea>
```

This of course works but not friendly:

```
<textarea id="Comments" name="Comments" rows="10" class="form-control">@Model.Comments</textarea>
```

---

Edited -- Oh well I created a custom editor template as such:

```
@{
string id = ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName;
string rows = string.Empty;
if (ViewData["rows"] != null)
{ 
    rows = string.Format("rows={0}", ViewData["rows"]);
}
}

<textarea id="@id" name="@id" @rows class="form-control">@Model</textarea>
```

Usage:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comments, "TextAreaCustom", new { @rows = 10 })
```

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, in the latest version of MVC (and maybe previous versions) you can set the col and rows to `0` and it won't render in the html.

This:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Comments, 0, 0, new { @class="form-control" })
```

Produces this:

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="Comments" name="Comments"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, you can't turn off an attribute that the helper adds by default; you can only change its value. This is mostly due to the fact that you can't set null items in an anonymous object, i.e. passing something like the following for `htmlAttributes` would raise an exception:

```
new { cols = null }
```

The only thing you can do, is leave it out of the anonymous object, but then the default takes over. One thing you can try is doing:

```
new { cols = "" }
```

Which should result in the generated HTML of

```
<textarea cols="" ...>
```

Not sure if that will actually work though; you'll have to test it. However, I'm using Bootstrap in my projects and I've never had to disable the `cols` attribute: it just works. What problem are you experiencing exactly with Bootstrap, because maybe that's something that *can* be fixed.

Comment: When the col attribute is not present BootStrap sets the text area to 100% of the div it is in.  Obviously when col is set it is that width so if he form changes size either the box looks too small or is bigger than the screen.  I am trying to set all my forms to use the xs/sm/md sizes based on browser size.

Comment: That was my point: the Bootstrap styles override the attribute, because they set an explicit width for the textarea. If that's not happening, then the Bootstrap styles are jacked somehow. Assuming the textarea has the requisite "form-control" class, the width should be 100% of the container, regardless of what `cols` is set to or if it's even set at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are rows and column attributes that you can set for TextAreaFor and it looks like by default it adds cols=20 and rows=2. Perhaps you can specify exactly what you want. Something like this for instance.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Commnets, new { @class = "whatever-class", @cols = 10 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no simple fix for this (unless you can consider JavaScript DOM manipulation)... you need to create your own HtmlHelper classes to use in your views...

Add the following class to your MVC project, and to use it... your views you can simply write `@this.Html.TextAreaHelperFor(...)` and use it the exact same way that you would use the `TextAreaFor` method, except the output wont be including any `col` or `row` attributes

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web;

using global::System.Web.Mvc;

public static class TextAreaHelperExtension
{
    public static MvcHtmlString TextAreaHelperFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        return TextAreaHelperFor(htmlHelper, expression, null);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString TextAreaHelperFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return TextAreaHelperFor(htmlHelper, expression, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString TextAreaHelperFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        if (expression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");
        }

        return TextAreaHelper(htmlHelper,
                                ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData),
                                ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression),
                                htmlAttributes);
    }

    internal static MvcHtmlString TextAreaHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata modelMetadata, string name, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes, string innerHtmlPrefix = null)
    {
        string fullName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("textarea");
        tagBuilder.GenerateId(fullName);
        tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes, true);
        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("name", fullName, true);

        ModelState modelState;
        if (htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(fullName, out modelState) && modelState.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            tagBuilder.AddCssClass(HtmlHelper.ValidationInputCssClassName);
        }

        tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(name, modelMetadata));

        string value;
        if (modelState != null && modelState.Value != null)
        {
            value = modelState.Value.AttemptedValue;
        }
        else if (modelMetadata.Model != null)
        {
            value = modelMetadata.Model.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            value = String.Empty;
        }

        tagBuilder.InnerHtml = (innerHtmlPrefix ?? Environment.NewLine) + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(value);

        return tagBuilder.ToMvcHtmlString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
    }

    internal static MvcHtmlString ToMvcHtmlString(this TagBuilder tagBuilder, TagRenderMode renderMode)
    {
        return new MvcHtmlString(tagBuilder.ToString(renderMode));
    }
}
```