# Bootstrap form layout incorrect when mobile width

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap v3.2.0 and trying to build a contact form with font awesome icons aligned to the left of the input fields. It renders fine in most widths apart from mobile (approx < 400px) where it places the icon on the line above the input box. Can someone point me in the right direction please? non of the @media css I've looked at is around 400px so I'm confused.

I can't post images yet, here is a link to screenshots of the issue:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rwnt8eeycpqlijx/AABCdhF2oRUG50mATrin_meYa?dl=0

code below (its all 1 block but I'm having issues posting it on here as 1)

Thanks

**EDIT
bootply here: http://www.bootply.com/WvUOSOyYaA**

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
           @Using Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post, New With {.enctype = "multipart/form-data", .class = "form-horizontal"})
               @<fieldset>
<legend class="header">Contact Me</legend>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x pull-right"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.FullName, New With {.class = "form-control pull-left", .placeholder = "Full Name"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.FullName)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x pull-right"></i>
        </div>
```

@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.EmailAddress, New With {.class = "form-control", .placeholder = "Email Address"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.EmailAddress)

```
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <i class="fa fa-wifi fa-2x pull-right"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.IPAddress, New With {.class = "form-control", .disabled = "disabled"})
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-2x pull-right"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(Function(m) m.Message, New With {.class = "form-control", .placeholder = "Enter your message for me here & I will get back to you asap..", .rows = "7"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Message)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

End Using

Comment: here is  a bootply of the issue:  http://www.bootply.com/WvUOSOyYaA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Html.TextAreaFor` is probably adding a cols attribute which is setting a min-width (effectively). I think that the default is 20 cols ... see [Disable cols with TextAreaFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981391/disable-cols-with-textareafor)

Comment: thanks for response. I've remove the '@html.TextAreaFor completely, I've set all the '@html.TextboxFor to have a width of 50px to test and still get the same issue.

Comment: If I remove width: 83.33333% from .col-xs-10 then I get your desired behavior, in fact any value <= 83% fixes the issue. So it isn't the width of the `<textarea>` but the width of the containing `<div class="col-xs-10">`. I guess at very small widths the sum of the widths including rounding errors is > 100% so the floated elements move down to accommodate this. Have you tried to put the awesome font icon within an input-group > input-group-icon? that way you might only need one col per row and they'll stack nicely for small screens

Comment: thanks for your help. I decided to go with an input-group-addon in the end.